# negative regex for password review

Tags: regex, passwords, expression

I have already tried several options on this topic here on Stackoverflow, but none of them worked.

I have a database of passwords that I need to review for compliance.

I figured how to build an expression to match the passwords that are compliant with the required complexity:

8-32 characters
letters
numbers
special characters

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[[:digit:]])(?=.*[[:punct:]]).{8,32}
```

Now, all I need to do is to get the negative of the above expression to find the password that do not match the required complexity.

I tried to change the expression to this:

```
(?!^(?=.{8,32}$)(?=.*[[:alpha:]])(?=.*[[:digit:]])(?=.*[[:punct:]])).*
```

but that does not work.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why not negate your test method. What tool are you using to run regex?

Comment: Or use a negative lookahead per assertion `^(?!.{8,32}$)(?!.*[[:alpha:]])(?!.*[[:digit:]])(?!.*[[:punct:]]).*`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I use https://regex101.com/ . Unfortunately the expression you suggested does not capture strings like "pass" as a password.

Comment: @Bluz That is because there is an alpha `(?!.*[[:alpha:]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse your assertion using negative lookahead with alternations like this:

```sh
^(?:(?!.*[a-z])|(?!.*[A-Z])|(?!.*[[:digit:]])|(?!.*[[:punct:]])|(?!.{8,32}$)).*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dlNwoC/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `(?!.*[a-z])`: we don't have a lowercase letter ahead
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?!.*[A-Z])`: we don't have a uppercase letter ahead
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?!.*[[:digit:]])`: we don't have a digit ahead
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?!.*[[:punct:]])`: we don't have a punctuation character ahead
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?!.{8,32}$)`: we don't have 8 to 32 characters ahead
- `)`:
- `.*`

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks very much @anubhava, this one seems to work. However, interestingly enough, it matches passwords such as "KJ+&)1O{v^R+q}" as negative pattern? I wonder if it's because arithmetic symbols do not count as :punct: ? - I'll give that a try and post back here.

Comment: ok I have just discovered fire hre but obviously, characters such as percentage,plus,minus,british pound sign, dollar, etc... do not seem to have a class of their own...

So, the expression I was looking for, with anubhava's help, was : 

/^(?:(?!.*[a-z])|(?!.*[A-Z])|(?!.*[[:digit:]])|(?!.*[[:punct:]])|(?!.{8,32}$)|(?!.*[\`\-\=\[\]\;\'\#\,\.\/\\\¬\!\"\£\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\{\}\:\@\~\<\>\?\|])).*

Comment: `KJ+&)1O{v^R+q}` is a valid password that's why it is not matched by above regex. Do you want to treat it as an invalid case?

Comment: Also please understand that `% + - $ # !` etc are all matched as punctuation symbols only.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will highlight bad passwords that are shorter than 8 characters, don't have special characters, upper/lower case letters and numbers:

```
/^(?:(?!.*[a-z])|(?!.*[A-Z])|(?!.*[[:digit:]])|(?!.*[[:punct:]])|(?!.{8,32}$)|(?!.*[\`\-\=\[\]\;\'\#\,\.\/\\\¬\!\"\£\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\{\}\:\@\~\<\>\?\|])).*
```